# Why preparedStmt.setString(1,"text'xx"); doesn't work as it could mess up the query (Java)?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Ok, I want to insert this String `text'xx` (which contain a single quotation) into table.

```
String sql="INSERT INTO table (text, id) values (?,?)";
  preparedStmt=myCon.prepareStatement(sql);
 preparedStmt.setString(1, "text'xx");
 preparedStmt.setInt(2,1);
 int affectedRows = preparedStmt.executeUpdate();
```

the I got this errr:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'text' at row 1
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2868)...
```

So i debugged & fount the sql is like this:

```
insert into table (text,id) values ('text'xx',1);
```

That is strage cos `preparedStmt.setString(1, "text'xx");` should be a very strong method & it should excapse everything right?

Or Am I misunderstanding something here?

How to fix it?

Comment: check what ' ' does in a String. what exactly do you want it to do? you may need an escape char to prevent issues there.

Comment: @Stultuske: There shouldn't be any need to escape it.

Comment: really?? I thought the prepareStmt will escapse for me?

Comment: @Tum: It should either escape it for you, or pass it along as a separate parameter value in the protocol. The code you've given looks  fine to me. When you say that you "found the sql was like this"... could it be that that's actually just a diagnostic representation which doesn't *really* show what was sent to the database? Which JDBC driver are you using? What's the size of the `text` field?

Comment: I'm not sure it should, but if the db consider it to be a second value, that could cause trouble.

Comment: size of the text is 500 chars

Comment: i am using MYSQl 5.0 , is that  an issue?

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: your string is too long. Please show the output of `show create table ...` - my guess is that the column is **not** defined as `varchar(500)`

Comment: CREATE TABLE `article` (
  `articleID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `text` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `html` varchar(5024) default NULL,

Comment: that is from my real DB, ...

Comment: What driver version are you using?

Comment: i think this could be a bug of MYSQL5 or JDK7. If I type the single quotation, then it's fine, but if I copy the single quotation from a Wikipedia then i got err

Comment: I used very old mysql-connector-java-5.0.4-bin.jar (20 Oct 2006)

Comment: try to test this String "iPhone (/ˈaɪfoʊn/ eye-fohn)", but do not copy from here, but open "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iphone" & copy the first 3 words to see if you got the same problem

Comment: In my case my table column was not in UTF-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

- Change your table name to another name that is not a [reserved
  word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html). (table2 in my example)
- Make sure your TEXT field is UTF-8

> ```
> **ALTER TABLE table2 MODIFY text VARCHAR(250) CHARACTER SET utf8;**
> ```

- Your IDE should be UTF-8 in eclipse Run
  configurations->common->encoding->UTF-8
- Specify UTF-8 in your mysql Connection

> jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8

- Make sure your code it UTF-8 (eclipse right-click on .java
  ->properties->utf-8

This works for me.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Connection myCon = null;
    try {
        String userName = "myuser", password = "mypass";// change accordingly
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8";// change accordingly
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        myCon = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
        PreparedStatement preparedStmt;
        try {
            String sql = "INSERT INTO table2 (text, id) values (?,?)";
            preparedStmt = myCon.prepareStatement(sql);
            preparedStmt.setString(1, "/ˈaɪfoʊn/ eye-fohn)");
            preparedStmt.setInt(2, 1);
            preparedStmt.executeUpdate();   
            preparedStmt = myCon.prepareStatement("SELECT id, text as text from table2 ");
            ResultSet rs = preparedStmt.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println("-->" +rs.getString("text") + "<--");
            }           
            preparedStmt.close();               
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (myCon != null) {
            try {
                myCon.close();
            } catch (Exception e) { }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think @Tum has just found a driver bug

Comment: I'm supposed to be using the same driver as him.

Comment: did u try to visit "en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iphone"; & copy the 1st 3 words like this "iPhone (/ˈaɪfoʊn/ eye-fohn)" & insert them in DB. Can u be able to insert it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code:-

```
String sql="INSERT INTO table_name (text, id) values (?,?)";
preparedStmt=myCon.prepareStatement(sql);
preparedStmt.setString(1, "text''xx");
preparedStmt.setInt(2,1);
int affectedRows = preparedStmt.executeUpdate();
```

here i changed your table name to table_name and purt an extra quote to "text'xx". this will convert your value to text'xx and will give no error. hope this will help you.

Comment: did u try to visit "en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iphone"; & copy the 1st 3 words like this "iPhone (/ˈaɪfoʊn/ eye-fohn)" & insert them in DB. Can u be able to insert it?